# Device owner, kiosk and Google EMM

Tags: android, kiosk, device-owner

maybe someone know , samsung have a powerfull core with name KNOX SDK.We have application which based on this sdk. And we are looking a way to do same application without knox sdk. But we stuck with simple function like kiosk mode. This mode not working if device owner is not setted for application (for me it's hard to understand) All what i found - it's this way :
[image]

This way is correct if im testing application myself. But when time is come and we will need to install this application on our 100-200 devices , then this way looks bad . Every device to do factory reset, and adb commands etc. 
So question : 
I'm sure there are should be a way to do this offically. But i can't find any info about this. Maybe some one know how to do this ? Please help. I'm sure i'm missed something somewhere. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can get information about the ways to provision device [here](https://developers.google.com/android/work/play/emm-api/prov-devices). They include:

- QR code
- Managed Google Play Accounts
- Google Account
- NFC

I've wrote an article where I've described provisioning with QR-code [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1253141/Developing-a-Kiosk-Application). We've selected this way for our Kiosk application as the most optimal one, because:

- zero touch enrolment works only on a small subset of devices;
- NFC provisioning requires another device with special app;
- Google Account requires having and managing this account.

On the other hand QR-code works almost on all Android 7.0+ devices ("almost" because some vendors disable this in their custom ROMs) and is easy to setup for end user.

But when you need to install it on multiple devices (and it's some internal app, so you do it yourself, rather than end user) Google Account can be more appropriate.

Comment: your post is very interesting . Can we somehow to connect via chat or somehow other way ? I still have a questions but looks like your way is what i need.

Comment: @Peter sure, you can find me e.g. in telegram: "ookami_kb".

Answer (score 1):

In production, you'll want to provision your [dedicated devices](https://developer.android.com/work/dpc/dedicated-devices) from the factory reset state (on the initial blue screen) using NFC, a QR code, or if supported, [zero touch enrollment](https://www.android.com/enterprise/management/zero-touch/). NFC can be used from another Android device using an app such as the [NFC provisioning app](https://github.com/android/enterprise-samples/tree/master/NfcProvisioning). A dedicated NFC card can also be programmed using an app such as [NFC Tools](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wakdev.wdnfc). Google provides provisioning instruction on their [TestDPC](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testdpc#provisioning) github repo. EMMs will also provide instructions for their DPC app. Using [Android Management](https://developers.google.com/android/management/quickstart) is usually a better alternative to TestDPC for production deployments under a 1000 devices. Additonal provisioning [options](https://developers.google.com/android/work/play/emm-api/prov-devices#Key_provisioning_differences_across_android_releases) and increased API usage limits are available if you're part of the [EMM Community](https://developers.google.com/android/work/play/emm-api/register).